# Install PSWindowsUpdate Module Issue

Tags: windows, powershell, module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEqP2.jpg)

Recently we want to update security and critical patches using command for customer's windows domain servers, and the PSWindowsUpdate Module seems is very suitable.
However, we tried to install it via "Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force" and also allow those servers can access Internet URL(*.microsoft.com/*.powershellgallery.com etc), but it still failed as screenshot
We google some links and use TLS1.2, however it still can't work and that very confused us that "WARNING: Source Location 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.3' is not valid."
I also tried to do that on my laptop with same method, it can work perfectly and there is no any error on powershell.
Customer windows server is Win2019 Datacenter and Standard
Customer powershell version is 5.1.17763.2931

We have no idea on the difference and how to install, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following command before installing PSWindowsupdate
Install-PackageProvider -name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force